# Ошибка при получении значения атрибута контекста (Результат)

Tags: 1с

Задача получить данные из Ексель файла, я загоняю данные в ТабличныйДокумент, потом использую его в запросе. Подскажите как быть.
Вот участок кода:

&НаСервере
Процедура СозданиеТабЛичногоДокументаИзФайла(ПутьКФайлу,ДопПарам) Экспорт

```
УстановитьПривилегированныйРежим(Истина);

Если НЕ ПутьКФайлу = Неопределено Тогда
    ПутьКФайлу = ПутьКФайлу[0]; 
    ТабДок = Новый ТабличныйДокумент;
    ТабДок.Прочитать(ПутьКФайлу,СпособЧтенияЗначенийТабличногоДокумента.Текст);
Иначе
    Возврат;
КонецЕсли;

ПостроительЗапроса = Новый ПостроительЗапроса;
ПостроительЗапроса.ИсточникДанных = Новый ОписаниеИсточникаДанных(ТабДок.Область(1,1,ТабДок.ВысотаТаблицы,ТабДок.ШиринаТаблицы));
ПостроительЗапроса.Выполнить();
Результат = ПостроительЗапроса.Результат; <-- **Вот тут вываливаемся с ошибкой**
ВыборкаТабДок = ПостроительЗапроса.Результат.Выбрать();
```

Comment: А зачем вам запрос? Почему просто не работать дальше с таб. доком?

Comment: ну мне кажется запрос более удобным.... Ошибка оказывается в том что первая строка в файле пустая, а так код работает.....

Comment: Чем именно удобней? Просто нет целой картины задачи. Можно по ячейкам таб. документа перемещаться и получать нужные данные.